# add unique id to requests forwarded from nginx reverse proxy

Tags: clojure, nginx, jetty, reverse-proxy, compojure

We are running nginx as a reverse proxy that forwards requests to a Clojure application running Compojure, a library that wraps around Jetty and provides our application with the ability to service web requests.

We currently capture logs generated by both nginx and the Clojure application (via log4j to syslog). We are unable, however, to match an entry in the nginx log to an entry in the syslog output of the Clojure application.

We need to figure out a way to modify the request sent upstream to the Clojure app to include some kind of ID. This could be an integer, UUID, whatever.

Do you have any suggestions as to how best to accomplish this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compojure is written on ring and ring has middleware :)

you would write a middleware called `with-uuid` that adds the UUID to the request map on the way in and to the reply on the way out.

Comment: Hm. I'll try that. Where in the request would you recommend I write the UUID. The header? I've not played around with nginx config. I'm assuming I'd have to write some code in the config file to lift the UUID out of the header and then write it out with log_format and access_log?

Comment: Hey. Finally got around to trying this. I was able to add an outgoing UUID but nginx is unable to capture it. I wrote up a new (possibly duplicative) entry here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272686/nginx-is-it-possible-to-capture-response-headers-in-access-log-when-using-nginx

Comment: I used the $upstream_http_HEADER variable in my nginx log_format configuration option to capture the outgoing uuid. See here for the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272686/nginx-is-it-possible-to-capture-response-headers-in-access-log-when-using-nginx

Answer (score 2):

Of course the best approach would be an nginx module, duplicating the functionality  of apache's mod_unique_id.

There doesn't seem to be one yet.  Here's a patch that wants to graduate to a module someday.:

http://mailman.nginx.org/pipermail/nginx-devel/2011-June/001015.html

Comment: There are at least two such modules -- https://github.com/newobj/nginx-x-rid-header (uses libuuid) and https://github.com/hhru/nginx_requestid