# nginx: Is it possible to capture response headers in access log when using nginx as a reverse proxy?

Tags: java, web-services, logging, clojure, nginx

We are using nginx as a reverse proxy to control and log access to a Clojure (Java) web service application.

We are able to generate an `access_log` and capture incoming headers using nginx just fine. Our Clojure app logs activity via log4j. Trouble is, is that we can't match an entry in the `access_log` to an entry generated by the app.

The app responds to access by sending response headers as well as a body. We can freely change these response headers. My initial thought was to generate a UUID that corresponds to each and every web service request and send that back to the user within the reply header `X-Uuid`. My thought was that I could capture this response by creating a custom `log_format`:

```
log_format lt-custom '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local]  '
                     '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                     '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" $request_time $http_x_uuid';
```

It's looking like nginx can capture headers in incoming requests but not outgoing replies (I verified this by replacing `$http_x_uuid` with `$http_content_type`).

So! Is there a way I can tie my `access_log` enties and my log4j entries by capturing outgoing reply headers using nginx? Is there a better way? I'd rather not have to rely on users generating their own UUIDs.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

$http_x_uuid is header sent by client.
Response header send by upstream is $upstream_http_x_uuid

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUpstreamModule#.24upstream_http_.24HEADER

Comment: the `_x` is for older versions of nginx, now it is just `$upstream_http_uuid` and `$http_uuid`