# Unique ID from nginx to node.js app?

Tags: node.js, nginx

We have nginx sitting in front of a node.js app. Is there any way to add a unique ID to a custom header at the nginx level that can be propogated to the app downstream? I have been researching around, and the closest I have got is [add unique id to requests forwarded from nginx reverse proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038559/add-unique-id-to-requests-forwarded-from-nginx-reverse-proxy).

Comment: Is this module https://github.com/newobj/nginx-x-rid-header the closest I can get?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like nginx doesn't support this functionality. a 3rd party extension is nowhere to be found either (?).

you can always add one more reverse proxy layer, e.g. apache (big) or proxpy (tiny) or whatever else, although doing that just for unique id is quite ridiculous.